# How to navigate to local file with ChromeDriver using a file path?

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, protractor-net

I am building a set of tests for an automation framework, but am running into an issue navigating to a local HTML page I have created.

Here is where I'm creating the `ChromeDriver` instance.

```
if (AllowFileAccessAcrossFiles)
{
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   // Have tried, none, individually, as well as both.
   options.AddArgument("--allow-file-access-from-files");
   options.AddArgument("--enable-local-file-accesses ");
   driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
}
```

This `ChromeDriver` instance is later passed into the `NgWebDriver` class so that I am able to use `Protractor-net` in my tests as well as abstract the test tools.

```
internal TestWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver driver, TestConfiguration configuration)
{
    // ...

    _driver = new NgWebDriver(driver);

    // ...
}
```

When the framework calls into the driver to navigate to the page it passes the correct file path ("file:/// ..."), but it never makes it into the browser URL and is not navigated to. (i.e. the URL says `data;`)

**How do I navigate to a local HTML page with a file path with `ChromeDriver`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this resolution to this issue is rooted in `NgWebDriver`. NgWebDriver defers to the drivers for IE, Edge, PhantomJS, Firefox, and Safari to navigate to the URL, but if it is anything else then it just runs this: `this.ExecuteScript("window.name += '" + AngularDeferBootstrap + "'; window.location.href = '" + value + "';");`

The [JavaScript method](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) that is being called doesn't handle just passing in a local path, it needs an http(s) string to navigate. So whether or not we can pass in a local path is up to the specific driver's implementation of the set method for the Url property.

Below is the relevant [Protractor-net](https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net/blob/master/src/Protractor/NgWebDriver.cs#L129) property.

```
public class NgWebDriver : IWebDriver, IWrapsDriver, IJavaScriptExecutor
{
    private const string AngularDeferBootstrap = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!";

    private IWebDriver driver;
    private IJavaScriptExecutor jsExecutor;
    private string rootElement;
    private IList<NgModule> mockModules;

    // constructors and stuff

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the URL the browser is currently displaying.
    /// </summary>
    public string Url
    {
        get
        {
            this.WaitForAngular();
            return this.driver.Url;
        }
        set
        {
            // Reset URL
            this.driver.Url = "about:blank";

            // TODO: test Android
            IHasCapabilities hcDriver = this.driver as IHasCapabilities;
            if (hcDriver != null &&
                (hcDriver.Capabilities.BrowserName == "internet explorer" ||
                 hcDriver.Capabilities.BrowserName == "MicrosoftEdge" ||
                 hcDriver.Capabilities.BrowserName == "phantomjs" ||
                 hcDriver.Capabilities.BrowserName == "firefox" ||
                 hcDriver.Capabilities.BrowserName.ToLower() == "safari"))
            {
                this.ExecuteScript("window.name += '" + AngularDeferBootstrap + "';");
                this.driver.Url = value;
            }
            else
            {
                this.ExecuteScript("window.name += '" + AngularDeferBootstrap + "'; window.location.href = '" + value + "';");
            }

            if (!this.IgnoreSynchronization)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Make sure the page is an Angular page.
                    long? angularVersion = this.ExecuteAsyncScript(ClientSideScripts.TestForAngular) as long?;
                    if (angularVersion.HasValue)
                    {
                        if (angularVersion.Value == 1)
                        {
                            // At this point, Angular will pause for us, until angular.resumeBootstrap is called.

                            // Add default module for Angular v1
                            this.mockModules.Add(new Ng1BaseModule());

                            // Register extra modules
                            foreach (NgModule ngModule in this.mockModules)
                            {
                                this.ExecuteScript(ngModule.Script);
                            }
                            // Resume Angular bootstrap
                            this.ExecuteScript(ClientSideScripts.ResumeAngularBootstrap,
                                String.Join(",", this.mockModules.Select(m => m.Name).ToArray()));
                        }
                        else if (angularVersion.Value == 2)
                        {
                            if (this.mockModules.Count > 0)
                            {
                                throw new NotSupportedException("Mock modules are not supported in Angular 2");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (WebDriverTimeoutException wdte)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        String.Format("Angular could not be found on the page '{0}'", value), wdte);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Since this property assumes that an application is using Angular, when navigating with `Navigate().GoToUrl()` you must include, again, whether the application is using Angular via a `bool`.**

In our case, we were not using Angular and passing that into the `GoToUrl()` method calls directly into the wrapped `IWebDriver` via `INavigation`. This wrapped driver handles local files correctly.

Below is the [navigation class](https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net/blob/master/src/Protractor/NgNavigation.cs) in Protractor-net:

```
public class NgNavigation : INavigation
{
    private NgWebDriver ngDriver;
    private INavigation navigation;

    // irrelevant constructors and such

    /// <summary>
    /// Load a new web page in the current browser window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The URL to load. It is best to use a fully qualified URL</param>
    /// <param name="ensureAngularApp">Ensure the page is an Angular page by throwing an exception.</param>
    public void GoToUrl(string url, bool ensureAngularApp)
    {
        if (ensureAngularApp)
        {
            this.ngDriver.Url = url;
        }
        else
        {
            this.navigation.GoToUrl(url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good find. Always fun to navigate the intricacies of the NgWebDriver laid on top of the other WebDrivers...